# In Windows Phone 8.1 how can I change the style of a ListView Item when it is selected

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have created a Win Phone 8.1 project showing a ListView where each item is displayed in a simple TextBlock. Just as in the first HubSection when you create a new project using the Hub App template under Store Apps -> Windows Phone Apps.

```
<HubSection x:Uid="HubSection1" Header="My Data">
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView
                    ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfData}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,16">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDataProperty}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

Now I am trying to figure out how I can change the style of the text in the selected ListViewItem TextBlock. That is I want the text to be set to bold for the selected item. I think I have done something similar using triggers previously.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this with `Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity` and HTML tags. Check this blog article: [Displaying HTML content in a TextBlock](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2015/01/16/Displaying-HTML-content-in-a-TextBlock.aspx). I have a fixed code for binding and styling, tell me if you will need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit ItemStyleContainer, then find `VisualState x:Name="Selected"` and change to this:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

You can change `<SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>` from red to your desire color